# How do I run BleachBit from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, automation, scripts, cleanup

On their website, they say to simply enter *bleachbit --(argument here)* but all that does is open the program. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The webpage about the command line interface haven't been updated since 09/07/2009 . The command line interface now has it's own binary, `bleachbit_cli`

```
info: starting BleachBit version 0.8.0
debug: appicon_path = '/usr/share/pixmaps/bleachbit.png'
Usage: bleachbit_cli [options] cleaner.option1 cleaner.option2

Options:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  -l, --list-cleaners  list cleaners
  -d, --delete         delete files and make other permanent changes
  --sysinfo            show system information
  -p, --preview        preview files to be deleted and other changes
  -v, --version        output version information and exit
  -o, --overwrite      overwrite files to hide contents
```

Answer (score 0):

lols love your reply:rtfm ;)

If you want to be able to answer your own questions re: using any prog from the cli/terminal emulator learn to use the man command the info command and the --help or -h flag

...in future you can type from the terminal window, the application name prefixed by "info" or suffixed by "--help or -h either will do same". You can also type "man programname" then hit enter/return then hit forward slashnospacesearchterm "/searchtermnospace" to find matches for any words you're interested in. Type "n" to advance to next occourance of search term within the manual.

Here is one of many pages that details how to search for what you want within a particular man page effectively check it out and practice a little. Learning this basic level will make using any program from the cli easier.

If you dont lke the format look online for nice alternatives (format wise looks sexy meh) eg Google "man alternatives online"
https://osxdaily.com/2016/08/27/search-man-pages-command-line/

that link pertains to mac but its unix/unix-like so meh. It applies for your situation.